# Nested dictionary behaving in a strange way

Tags: defaultdict

I have a list of text files, each representing a year, starting from 1880 and going all the way up to 2014. Each file contains a list of names, genders and the number of occurrences of that name in that year, similar to this:

Mary,F,14406

Anna,F,5773

Helen,F,5230

Now, I want to create a function that reads all the files and returns a nested dictionary of the form:

name -> year -> count

That is, name is the key and its value is another dictionary in which I add all the years as keys and the number of occurrences of a name as their value.

This is what I've come up with:

```
def files_to_dict(folder_name):

  dic = defaultdict(dict)

  for filename in glob.glob( os.path.join( folder_name, '*.txt' )):

      with open( filename, 'r' ) as yearFile:

          # Each file is named yob[year].txt e.g yob2011.txt, hence  
          # I'm slicing the filename to get just the year. 

             year = int(filename[9:13])

             for line in yearFile:

              # [0] = Name, [1] = Gender, [2] = Total Occurrences of Name
              list_of_line = line.replace(',',' ').split()

              dic[ list_of_line[0] ][ year ] = int( list_of_line[2] )

  return dic
```

Now If I do this:

```
d = files_to_dict( 'names' )
print ( d['Mary'] )
```

I get something like this. (only showing last 10 years):

```
...2004: 31, 2005: 10, 2006: 10, 2007: 10, 2008: 3490, 2009: 3154, 2010: 
   2862, 2011: 2701, 2012: 6, 2013: 2632, 2014: 5}
```

Here, 2008 - 2011 all have the correct counts as they appear in the files, but
2004 - 2007 and 2012 and 2014 all have incorrect counts. This is what happens with the whole output. Most of the counts are wrong and only a dozen or so contain the correct tally of names. I really don't understand why this is so. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you made sure that all the files have the exact same format (Name,Gender,Count)? I replicated your program on my machine with some dummy data and it appears to work fine for me

Comment: @mattjegan Ok so I figured out the error and its pretty stupid of me to be honest. The thing is, I was only using the name as the key and not the gender, so in the instances when the correct count is shown, the name with the "correct" gender is being saved into the dictionary and in the instances when the count is off, the name with the  "incorrect" gender is being used. I mean, who knew there are dudes named Mary out there.